# R Web Scraping 'Failed to load HTTP Resource' with XML

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping

I have created a function to scrape statistics from individual soccer match reports. I am usually able to use this to scrape stats from hundreds of matches at a time without a problem. However for the past week I have been away visiting family for the holidays cannot run my code at all without receiving the message:

```
Error: failed to load HTTP resource
```

I thought this was just my parents poor internet connection but I am now having the same problem wherever I go around the country!

My code starts with creating a vector of match codes for each game:

```
matchid <- c(369835, 369842, 369839, 369836, 369834, 369841)
```

My function is currently as below:

```
GetStats <- function(matchid){
Stats <- NULL
for(i in matchid){
urli <- paste("http://www.espnfc.co.uk/gamecast/statistics/id/", i, "/statistics.html", sep="")
datai <- readHTMLTable(urli)
hometeami <- datai[[1]]
awayteami <- datai[[2]]
hometeami <- hometeami[1:11,]
awayteami <- awayteami[1:11,]
matchdatai <- rbind(hometeami, awayteami)
matchdatai$match_id <- i
matchdatai <- matchdatai[c(14, 1:13)]
Stats <- rbind(Stats, matchdatai)}
return(Stats)
}
```

I then run my function on my individual match codes:

```
MatchStats <- GetStats(matchid)
View(MatchStats)
```

But it is at this point that I am now receive the error message.

Could someone please help me by helping me understand what might be causing this? As far as I can see nothing has changed in the websites I am trying to scrape. Is it something caused by the internet connections I am now using? Is there a simple fix I can add in to my code to overcome this?

As mentioned, I am able to run this on hundreds of matches at once on my own connection at my flat so I am very confused!

Thank you in advance

Comment: what happens when you go the the URL from a browser at the places it doesn't work from the script?

Comment: Hi, I just checked loading the pages individually in Chrome and I would say that 9 times out of 10 they all load correctly. But I do sometimes get a message "this page does not exist or has been moved" yet when I refresh the page it always loads the second time.

Comment: I actually got the error the first time I ran your code but it worked every time after that. It looks like you're getting a random server issue. I can suggest switching to the `rvest` or `httr` packages and trapping non "200" server errors then retrying "x" number of times per request. `rvest` has an `html_table` function, too. However, I can't help you anymore unless you can provide proof you've received permission to do this scraping - http://disneytermsofuse.com/english/ (that's the ESPN UK ToS and it prohibits scraping).

Comment: OK thanks for your help. I wasn't aware of the ToS so will have to look at alternatives

Comment: I have been playing around with httr and GET() going through one webpage at a time and the error and when the web page does not load correctly it is a status 500. From what I am reading about status 500 am I right in thinking this is not something wrong with my connection but with the site I am using?

Comment: Right. That's definitely a site issue.